# BCS connection with SQL DB and Sharepoint list passing parameters

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, bcs, sql-server

Is there way to pass parameters to BCS connection between sharepoint list and sql table and populate the list with the sql table data which agrees to a certain scenario(according to the passed parameters)? If so please share documentation for doing so... if you have any..